# Watson Retrieve and Rank does not show uploaded document in the list of answers to be ranked

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

This is the html document created using https://document-conversion-demo.mybluemix.net/  .Uploaded this documents using R&R WebUI, when I rank a question: What is spring boot?  this document is not displayed in the list of answers. Has this document not been ingested correctly ?

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?><html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<style type="text/css">/**//**/</style>
<meta content="kapoor" name="author"/>
<meta content="2016-09-20" name="publicationdate"/>

<title>no title</title></head>
<body class="b1">

<div id="content">
<p dir="ltr">
<a href="http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/%22 \t %22_blank">Spring Boot</a>  is an application-bootstrapping framework that helps with the creation of Spring based applications with no necessary XML configuration or code generation.  It eases the configuration with its starter pom definitions and bootstrap annotations.</p>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the question mark is causing the problem. Try removing the question mark from the question, or use the Add Another Answer button to try searching for "What is Spring Boot" or just "Spring Boot"

*(**Update 26th Sept:** Fixes to the web tool since I posted this answer mean that this should no longer be necessary)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Dale. I am getting a Solr exception that the document is not formatted correctly. I am thinking probably the title of the document has to be added to the document being uploaded, which I will try.